# AutoMock v5 behavior

Tags: autofac

Upgrading Nuget packages from Autofac v4.9.4 and Autofac.Extras.Moq v4.3.0 to latest (5.1.2 and 5.0.1) changes the behavior of mock.Create(). This test passes in v4 and fails in v5.

```
public class SystemUnderTest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        using var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose();
        var sut1 = mock.Create<SystemUnderTest>();
        sut1.Id = 1;
        var sut2 = mock.Create<SystemUnderTest>();
        sut2.Id.Should().NotBe(1); // this fails in v5 because sut2 is sut1. 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to restore the old behavior, or a workaround that doesn't involve mocking constructor parameters manually?

Comment: I wound up mocking each constructor parameter manually. Now if I add some trivial service I will need to modify my unit test as well. Feels bad. The old behavior worked well for me.